# How to combine near schedules in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with two properties (Start and End).  I need to be able to take items whose times fall within a variable (config option) tolerance level and combine them.

**Example:**

*Tolerance:* 1 hour

```
Item A: Start = 1pm, End = 2pm
Item B: Start 2:30pm, End = 4pm
```

Since the tolerance is one hour, I need to be able to 'combine' these two into a single timespan or other like object with, in this example, the following stats:

```
Start = 1pm, End 4pm
```

A sample class that I am using for testing follows.  The production class has two like properties, along with several others.

```
public class TimeTest
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

}
```

I guess my confusion point is if there is an elegant way of doing this in LINQ.  I'm still wrestling with how to compare a list item to another list item and iterate through the list that way.

Comment: What happens with three items where 1 and 2 are within an hour and 2 and 3 are within an hour?

Comment: If those are `DateTime` objects, subtracting them will give you a difference `TimeSpan`.

Comment: all need to be combined.  So if 1 is 1pm to 2pm, 2 is 2:30pm to 4pm and 3 is 5pm to 6pm, The final output time needs to be 1pm - 6pm.

Comment: Can you post what the objects look like, and perhaps some example code where you tried to do this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to iterate a sequence and use some criteria to sometimes combine consecutive items into a single item you can use an iterator block to keep state about the "previous" item while iterating:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Item> Combine(this IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        using (var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield break;

            var previous = enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var next = enumerator.Current;

                if (TryCombine(previous, next, out var combined))
                {
                    previous = combined;
                    continue;
                }

                yield return previous;
                previous = next;
            }
            yield return previous;
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to implement `TryCombine` to apply your logic. Based on your requirements something like this should work for you:

```
private static bool TryCombine(Item item1, Item item2, out Item combinedItem)
{
    if (item2.Start - item1.End > TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
    {
        combinedItem = default;
        return false;
    }

    combinedItem = new Item { Start = item1.Start, End = item2.End };
    return true;
}
```

Since this method is an extension method you can use it like this:

```
var combinedItems = items.Combine();
```

For more flexibility you could provide the 1 hour threshold as a `TimeSpan` parameter to the method and also perhaps use some more descriptive names instead of `Item` and `Combine` that makes more sense in your domain.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Very elegant and very helpful.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a simple Min/Max situation.

```
List<TimeTest> times = new List<TimeTest>();
//... Fill list
if(times.Count == 0) return;
int min = Int32.MaxValue;
int max = Int32.MinValue;
foreach(var item in times)
{
    min = Math.Min(item.Start.Hour, min);
    max = Math.Max(item.End.Hour, max);
}
```

Then initialize a 1pm - 4pm construct as you see fit as `min` and `max` will contain your start and end times.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this, using Aggregate.

For Input

```
var list = new List<Interval>
    {
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,13,0,0), End=new DateTime(2019,1,1,14,0,0)},
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,14,30,0), End=new DateTime(2019,1,1,16,0,0)},
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,16,0,0), End=new DateTime(2019,1,1,17,0,0)},
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,19,0,0), End=new DateTime(2019,1,1,20,0,0)},
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,22,0,0), End=new DateTime(2019,1,1,23,0,0)},
        new Interval{Start=new DateTime(2019,1,1,23,40,0), End=new DateTime(2019,2,1,2,0,0)},
    };
```

Where Interval is defined as

```
public class Interval
{   

    public DateTime Start{get;set;}
    public DateTime End{get;set;}
}
```

You can

```
var result = MergeAndList(list);
```

Where MergeAndList is defined as

```
IEnumerable<Interval> MergeAndList(IEnumerable<Interval> intervals) 
{

var ret = new List<Interval>(intervals);
int lastCount=0;
do
{
    lastCount = ret.Count;
    ret = ret.Aggregate(new List<Interval>(),(agg, cur) =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < agg.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var a = agg[i];
                        if(a.End.AddHours(1) >= cur.Start)
                        {
                         agg[i] = new Interval{Start=a.Start, End=cur.End};
                         return agg;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            agg[i] = new Interval{Start=a.Start, End=a.End};
                        }
                    }
                    agg.Add(cur);
                    return agg;
                });
} while (ret.Count != lastCount);
return ret;
}
```

Output

[image]

[Example in Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBAVNJ)